Troubles with Azure Alerts using management group scope
I am trying to set up an alert within Azure that alerts me whenever the operationname, "Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/write", is triggered in the Activity Log. The problem I am having is explained below.
In the activity log, I can search for this operation name within the Management Group level. This can be seen in the image below.
Activity Log Query
While creating an alert, the only option I'm given for scope selection are subscriptions, not management groups. The OperationName is only stored at the management group level and not at the subscription level.
I'm currently trying to send the logs to a log analytics workspace using the Diagnostic settings. I've set this up with an alert that specifically queries for "Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/write" as seen below.
AzureActivity
| where OperationName == "Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/write"

I've intentionally triggered this event multiple times over a period of 30 minutes and don't see any alerts, or and data when querying the LAW logs.
With this all said, I am unsure if the LAW is capturing the activity logs at the management group level or at the subscription level.
Any advice or guidance to documentation is most welcome.
I've been pondering using an event grid function to gather the data. I have something similar set up for something else that needs access to the activity logs, would it be better to set up the capture data or set an alert through a function?

Are you still facing the issue. @SRoberts

To create diagnostic settings using Azure CLI, you need to use
az monitor diagnostic-settings create command available in Azure.
az monitor diagnostic-settings create `
  --name "MgDiagnostics" `
  --resource "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/xxxxx7b19afd6" `
  --resource-type "Microsoft.Management/managementGroups" `
  --logs '[{"category": "Administrative", "enabled": true}]' `
  --metrics "[{\"category\":\"AllMetrics\",\"enabled\":true}]" `
  --workspace "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/arkorg/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/loganalyticsname"

To retrieve the ID of a management group, use az account management-group list command for your reference. Make sure that you have necessary permissions to obtain the details.
Alternatively, check here for creation with PowerShell approach.
